# netbeans sql application fails on startup

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I've built a java application with netbeans and gone ahead and bound a mySql database table to a jtable using the UI. (This was very early on in both my java learning curve and the program itself. I know now I should have built it all by hand but it's part of a much larger application and this is the only problem).

It all works fine unless the application can't find the db in which case the program won't load at all. I would like to be able to give some sort of feedback here like "Can't find database. Program will close." but I can't seem to get access to any of that behind the scenes netbeans init code.

Running in debug basically shows that the application fails on 'initComponents()' but gives no other clues. Stepping into debug gets as far as 'launch'.

I'm using a wamp server on windows with standard mysql database.

Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Jeff

... Here's some of the generated code to give you an idea of what I'm doing;

```
bindingGroup = new org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BindingGroup();
private javax.persistence.Query riderinfoQuery;

xscPUEntityManager = java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime() ? null : javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("xscPU").createEntityManager();

riderinfoQuery = java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime() ? null : xscPUEntityManager.createQuery("SELECT r FROM Riderinfo r");
riderinfoList = java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime() ? java.util.Collections.emptyList() : riderinfoQuery.getResultList();

org.jdesktop.swingbinding.JTableBinding jTableBinding = org.jdesktop.swingbinding.SwingBindings.createJTableBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.AutoBinding.UpdateStrategy.READ_WRITE, riderinfoList, jTable1);
org.jdesktop.swingbinding.JTableBinding.ColumnBinding columnBinding = jTableBinding.addColumnBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${memberNumber}"));
columnBinding.setColumnName("Member Number");
columnBinding.setColumnClass(Integer.class);
```

...... etc. and then towards the end;

```
private java.util.List<xsclookup.Riderinfo> riderinfoList;
private javax.persistence.Query riderinfoQuery;
```

But,as I say, this is all in the protected 'generated for you' section of the program.

Comment: show us your code. Atleast the database connectivity part of code.

Comment: also if possible screenshot...